# Using pattern matching, how can i call a method from a T base

Tags: c#, generics, pattern-matching

Im creating a viewmodel base where each viewmodel has a collection and a method to reload the collection.

```
public interface ILegalViewModelBase<T>
{
    ObservableCollection<T> MasterCollection { get; set; }
    void ReloadCollection();
}

public abstract class LegalViewModelBase<T> : BindableBase, ILegalViewModelBase<T>
{
    public ObservableCollection<T> MasterCollection
    {
        get => _masterCollection;
        set => SetProperty(ref _masterCollection, value, ReloadCollection);
    }
    private ObservableCollection<T> _masterCollection;

    public abstract void ReloadCollection();
}
```

in Codebehind, im trying to determine if the DataContext is of type `ILegalViewModelBase` and if it is, call the `ReloadCollection()` method.
(Im aware that this 'breaks' mvvm.)

i can check if its of `T` using the following code

```
if (DataContext.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ILegalViewModelBase<>) /* typeof(ILegalViewModelBase<>) */)
{
    ....
}
```

but im having trouble figuring out how to cast it into a usable object. ive done it before with non-generic classes using the code below.

```
if (DataContext is AttorneyClaimsViewModel vm)
{
    vm.ReloadCollection();
}
```

How would i do the same with generics?

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from moving the `ReloadCollection` method to a non generic interface, and have the generic interface extend the non-generic interface?

Comment: Trying not to repeat myself, Theres 4 models, and the viewmodels were basically the same with the exception of the business objects. I figured it'd make more sense to create a generic base. In codebehind, ill check which `viewmodel` is shown, and reload that one

Comment: Just move `ReloadCollection` to parent non-generic interface as first comment suggests. It will cost you 3 lines of code.

Comment: Sorry i misread, im gonna google how to extend the non-generic interface,

Comment: You are not repeating anything, you are just creating a two level interface hierarchy. `ReloadCollection` doesn't need a generic interface. The generic interface is hurting you. The obvious solution is: don't use a generic interface for that method.

Comment: @M.Aroosi i guess 1 thing that prevents me from doing that is when `MasterCollection` is set, `ReloadCollection` gets called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that using generics. The reason for that is that you could wouldn't know what `T` is at that point:

```
if (DataContext is LegalViewModelBase<> vm)
{
    var col = vm.MasterCollection; // What type is col??
}
```

In your specific case, you're not interested in the collection, but rather in the method that is indifferent from the type parameter. In that case, move it up to a different non-generic interface and you'll be able to use pattern matching:

```
public interface ILegalViewModelBase 
{
    void ReloadCollection();
}

public interface ILegalViewModelBase<T> : ILegalViewModelBase
{
    ObservableCollection<T> MasterCollection { get; set; }
}

public abstract class LegalViewModelBase<T> : BindableBase, ILegalViewModelBase<T>
{
    public ObservableCollection<T> MasterCollection
    {
        get => _masterCollection;
        set => SetProperty(ref _masterCollection, value, ReloadCollection);
    }
    private ObservableCollection<T> _masterCollection;
}
```

Now you can use the base interface for pattern matching:

```
if (DataContext is ILegalViewModelBase vm)
{
    vm.ReloadCollection();
}
```

Comment: this works perfectly, and opens a new way of thinking for me. thanks